# Can we set local image to SDWebImage’s offline image?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I’m using

```
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

To download images in my application, I found that all the images were downloaded in ***“/Library/Caches/com.bundlename.bundlename/com.alamofire.imagedownloader/fsCachedData”*** with some unique names.

My app has offline support and I have managed CoreData Entity for the image with file path(files are in library caches directory), As I Upload my images my server will respond with my S3 file URL to download.

As I (the user who upload file) have an image file already but SDWebImage did not know that. So it will download the file again.

Any suggestion what should I do to manage it without downloading the same image again? I can not keep local path in my database as my app has sync function with multiple devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use SDImageCache for this purpose.
Sample code:

```
NSArray<NSString*> *urls = @"aws s3 url here";
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] diskImageExistsWithKey:urls[0] completion:^(BOOL isInCache) {
        if ( isInCache ) {
            [yourImage setImage:[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:urls[0]]];
        } else {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:item.url];
            [yourImage sd_setImageWithURL:url completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {
                [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image forKey:urls[0] toDisk:YES completion:^{

                }];
                [yourImage setImage:image];
            }];
        }
    }] ;
```